# Change tab bar in storyboard dynamically

Tags: storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I am trying to work with story board. I am adding tab bar controller and 3 viewcontrollers to that. On first view I have a button and on that button click I want to remove third tab so that there will be 2 tab present.

I am  using below code to remove last tab

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllersCopy = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
[viewControllersCopy removeObjectAtIndex:2];
NSArray *modifiedViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:viewControllersCopy];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:modifiedViewControllers animated:NO];
```

but it is crashing by giving error

> Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed

I have seen many links but not able to find any fine answer for it.

Thanks to frin.

Now I have updated my code to work with navigation controller. Previously it was dealing to view controller.
I am using below code to change tab bar

```
UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone"
                                              bundle:nil];
UIViewController* vc1 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
NSMutableArray *viewControllersCopy = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
[viewControllersCopy replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:nav];
NSArray *modifiedViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:viewControllersCopy];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:modifiedViewControllers animated:NO];
```

It is working fine but when I am setting tab bar image it is not set.

If I am using

```
    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone"
                                              bundle:nil];
UIViewController* vc1 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
NSMutableArray *viewControllersCopy = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
[viewControllersCopy replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:vc1];
NSArray *modifiedViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:viewControllersCopy];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:modifiedViewControllers animated:NO];
```

Then tab bar image is set but navigation is  not showing.

Is there any way to get directly navigation controller from the story board or there is any way to show tab bar image?

https://github.com/mayankpurwar/sample is my code link.

Comment: Are you sure you are using latest Xcode? This code works perfectly fine for me. The error does not seem logical to the code you posted, usually you get this error when you modify the tabbar of UITabBarController directly, instead of changing the viewcontrollers array.

Comment: I am using latest xcode. Is there any way to upload code. I can upload my code to show you.

Comment: I am sending my code link https://github.com/mayankpurwar/sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is as I expected not with the code you posted in question, but directly modifying the tabbar on UITabBarController, on line 40 in file FirstViewController.m:

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[arr objectAtIndex:0],[arr objectAtIndex:1], nil]];
```

Comment this line, the code at line #67 will properly remove the last tab. Also the code at line #84 will crash as well if a tab with name "Item" is found.

To find the location of the crash next time, go to Breakpoint Navigator (Cmd + 7 or View>Navigators>Show Breakpoint Navigator), click the plus icon in bottom left corner, Add Exception Breakpoint. A new breakpoint is made automatically. If you run your code with this breakpoint, it will stop at line #40.

[image]

Comment: You are right. Thanks for answering. I have one more issue when I am replacing tab its showing black. I have updated some code in FirstViewController.m. Please check and tell me why its showing black.